# Logger in java issue, doubling

Tags: java, logging, properties

Here is code of LoggerHelper class and after executing main there are 55 lines of useless thing there should be only 10 lines. I also add logging.properties probably i should add something here but i don't know what. Here i also give output of log.log file. https://code.skript.pl/SQ1gUc2d. Oh i almost forgot here is console output: https://code.skript.pl/hyufygAJ

```
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());
private static Handler fileHandler;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        log(Level.INFO, true, "Message: " + i);
    }
}

public static void log(Level level, Boolean console, String... message) {
    fileHandler.setFormatter(new LogFormatter());
    logger.setUseParentHandlers(console);
    logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
    switch (String.valueOf(level)) {
        case "INFO":
            for (String string : message) {
                logger.info(string);
            }
            break;
        case "WARNING":
            for (String string : message) {
                logger.warning(string);
            }
            break;
        case "SEVERE":
            for (String string : message) {
                logger.severe(string);
            }
            break;
        case "CONFIG":
            for (String string : message) {
                logger.config(string);
            }
            break;
        default:
            for (String string : message) {
                logger.fine(string);
            }
            break;
    }

} static {
    try {
        LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("logging.properties"));
        fileHandler = new FileHandler("Logs/log.log", 0, 1, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=[%1$tF %1$tT] [%4$-7s] %5$s %n
```

Comment: You add a file handler on every call.

Comment: What’s the point of doing this?  It doesn’t seem to improve on the existing methods of the Logger class at all.

Comment: @DaveNewton when i did this it is creating single file everytime methode is being executed

Comment: @VGR the point is to save some console output in filoe